# Estimate total sum of joined tables

Tags: sql-server, subquery, grouping

I already join five database. And the end I come to last step of my calculation, but here some problem arise. You can see code code below :

```
DECLARE @Locations TABLE (LocationId int)
INSERT INTO @Locations  values ('5'), ('2')
SELECT a.Id, A.CityId
FROM dbo.Location a
INNER JOIN @Locations lo ON lo.LocationId = a.cityid
SELECT my.Id,SUM((acc.Amount)) AS Outflow
FROM #Customers as my
INNER JOIN dbo.AccountDetails as acc ON acc.AccountId=my.Id
INNER JOIN @Locations lo ON lo.LocationId =acc.LocationId
GROUP BY my.id
```

So here my intention is to get sum of all transactions of customers stored into table #Customers.But here I have some problem. Namely  code above give results same of each customer stored into table #Customers.Each of this spend different amount and results should be different for each consumer. You can see output below (marked with yellow color).

[image]

Probably my mistake is SUM or GROUP function, so  can anybody help me how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Do you want the sum of transaction value by customer id? If so, why have you joined location?

Comment: Yes.You are right.I will check in that direction

Comment: What is the schema of the table that stores transaction details?

Comment: Actually I omit last line of code which is  unnecessary. If you want I can send diagram of all tables :) BR